# Mercurial/TortoiseHG - Append branchname to commit message automatically?

Tags: mercurial, branch, commit, tortoisehg

So we work in "named" branches with what we do, but it's now come to light that this "name" we use should also be used in the commit message to help with tracking etc.

If we're using TortoiseHG or Mercurial, is there a way to automatically append/preappend the brnachname to the commit message?

I've looked around and can't find anything that matches exactly what we need :(

So for example:

hg commit "did a change" in the "RR-3498" branch will become something like

```
"RR-3498 did a change"
```

or

```
"did a change RR-3498"
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain "to help with tracking etc"? Are you using some other tool that gives you the commit message without the context of the branch name? If so, I'd start by figuring out how to fix the problem there.

Comment: I don't know Windows, but in Linux this would be very easy: `hg commit -m "$(hg branch) did a change"`

Answer (score 2):

> this "name" we use should also be used in the commit message

Branch name **must NOT be used** (*I can not emphasize more strongly here*) in commit message - it's redundant, duplicate information, which require additional actions for extracting from log message for processing

Branch-name in Mercurial is **permanent** meta-data, **always** stored in **each** changeset.

If you use Mercurial for "tracking", then the most of usable commands (I can imagine only `hg log` for now) are templateable, and you can output branch name easy. If you use some external tool, you can on preparing data for it from Mercurial combine "clean" commit-message and branch-name of changesets

<sub>Don't forget about MYOB principle</sub>

Comment: We require it in the commit message, hence me asking. Regardless of duplication, you do not know the background of it (and it's not something I can go into), but we require it :)

Comment: Like I said in my comment directly on the question, the only reason I can imagine for wanting the branch name in the commit message is because of some other (badly designed) tool or process that somehow can't directly use the branch name when it should be able to. Fix that other tool or process, and this requirement goes away. What's next? We'll need to include the timestamp and the author's name in each commit message? This way lies madness.

Comment: Exactly right, its for another tool. But it's a tool we cannot fix as it's third-party licensed, so therefore I was hoping of doing this so it saves me time/remembering to do it :) If I could fix the tool in question, or do it properly, then believe me I would! However, the question is exactly as I want/need it, but am not sure how to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a hook for this.
That said, this requirement sounds like from a pointed-hair manager.